# most efficient way to vectorize 2d arrays in scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have

```
val A = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6))
```

where each entry corresponds to a row of a matrix. What is the most efficient way to vectorize (columnwise) this into
 `val vec = Array(1,4,2,5,3,6)`?

What I am currently implementing is `val vec = A.transpose.flatten`. Is that the most efficient method?

Comment: You could write your own code based on those two to do it in one pass, but the other measure of "efficiency" (you and future maintainer's time) would argue to do it the way you are, unless and until you know that really is a  key contributor to your overall performance.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul - Keep in mind that it's a _big_ performance difference, though (see my answer), so it could well have an impact.

Comment: Yes. agreed. I still have a twitch when I see questions about how to make an isolated fragment "efficient", though - especially when not accompanied by any explanation of why the efficiency is important to the OP's overall application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way is to do it the old way: loop through indices.

```
def transposeFlat(a: Array[Array[Int]]): Array[Int] = {
  var n = 0
  var i = 0
  while (i < a.length) { n += a(i).length; i += 1 }
  val b = new Array[Int](n)
  val m = n / a.length;
  i = 0
  var j = 0
  while (j < m) {
    var k = 0
    while (k < a.length) {
      b(i) = a(k)(j)
      i += 1
      k += 1
    }
    j += 1
  }
  b
}
```

This is about 10x faster than `transpose.flatten` (depending on how well the JVM optimizes things, it ranges from 8-18x on my machine with an 64 x 256 array, and up to 50x faster if there is only a single row so the `transpose.flatten` pointlessly creates a single-element array for every element before flattening it).

The reason for the large performance difference is twofold.  First, the method I wrote doesn't create any intermediate collections.  Second, the `Array` operations are not specialized for primitives, so there's overhead for doing it generically.